# Maven Exclusion for specific version

Tags: maven

I have a project with a maven dependency that pulls in two packages, one of which pulls in a sub-dependency which is the same package of a lower version than the other. The `dependency:tree` looks like this:

```
Dependency convergence error for xerces:xercesImpl:2.10.0 paths to dependency are:
+-com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiler:7.6.4
  +-net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:1.9.19
     +-xerces:xercesImpl:2.10.0
and
+-com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiler:7.6.4
  +-xerces:xercesImpl:2.11.0
```

The above is an output from the maven enforcer plugin where I'm enforcing dependency version convergence.

Is there a way that I can specify a version to exclude without excluding the entire sub-dependency altogether?

Answer (score 7):

Declare the net.sourceforge.nekohtml dependency in your pom.xml as a first-degree dependency, and add an exclusion to it directly.

Reference: [Maven Optional and Excludes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
   <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
   <version>1.9.19</version>
   <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: so what to do if artifact duplicate is within another dependency?

Comment: You add the exclusion rule to that dependency. Tools can help you here. For example, Eclipse has a pom.xml viewer with tabs at the bottom. You can click the tabs on the bottom to explore dependencies, then r click on one and say “exclude”. Eclipse will then prompt you as to where you want to add the exclusion.

Comment: i think unversal way would be to exclude of confilct dependency (for com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiler in example above), and add xercesImpl dependency with concrete version before vaadin-client-compiler.